# How to write types for state with objects in react using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript. I dont know how to write types for my id name price and q. How to do this? 
Tell me how to do it please

```
type State = {
  data:[],
  id:number,
  name:string,
  price: string,
  q: number,
  count: []
}
class Shop extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Product 1",
          price: "50",
          q: 0
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Product 2",
          price: "70",
          q: 0
        }
      ],
      count: []
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrap">
        <ProductList products={this.state.data} />
        <CartList cart={this.state.count} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Shop />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type 'Readonly'

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an array containing objects that have those properties:

```
type State = {
  data: {
    id:number,
    name:string,
    price: string,
    q: number
  }[],
  count: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a type defined for your data? I don't see one, but you'd want to use that or create one if it doesn't exist. For example:

```
type Data = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: string;
  q: number;
}

type State = {
  data: Data[],
  count: any[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type definition of data should contain the object properties.

```
type StateDataElement = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  price: string,
  q: number
}

type State = {
  data: StateElement[],
  count: []
}
```